# Dynamically initialize array size in go

Tags: arrays, go

I try to write a small application in go that takes 'x' numbers of integers from standard input, calculates the mean and gives it back. I have only gotten so far:

```
func main() {
var elems, mean int
sum := 0

fmt.Print("Number of elements? ")

fmt.Scan(&elems)

var array = new([elems]int)

for i := 0; i < elems; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%d . Number? ", i+1)
    fmt.Scan(&array[i])
    sum += array[i];
}............
```

When trying to compile this I get the following error message:

> invalid array bound elems

What is wrong here?

Comment: i saw this somewhere already :) let me guess https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum/problem?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You should use a slice instead of an array:

```
//var array = new([elems]int) - no, arrays are not dynamic
var slice = make([]int,elems) // or slice := make([]int, elems)
```

See "[go slices usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/2011/01/go-slices-usage-and-internals.html)". Also you may want to consider [using range](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) for your loop:

```
// for i := 0; i < elems; i++ { - correct but less idiomatic
for i, v := range slice {
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! Exactly what I sought :)

Comment: @Paolo: You would need to write "for i,_ := range array {}". In my opinion, using "for i:=0; i<elems; i++ {}" seems more appropriate here. In either case, there is no need to use an array in this program.

Comment: @Atom: I thought he could use `v` instead of  `array[i]` in the loop. But I agree that my search for _idiomatic_ code is sometimes exaggerated (I'm one of those people who, when abroad, look for _typical_ restaurants and get _typically_ ripped off)

Comment: Should be `slice := make([]int, elems)` to avoid confusion.

Comment: if it's "dynamic", why we need to set the length of the slice?

Comment: @PaoloFalabella I already found an answer. The dynamic array In Go actually doesn't need length. It can declared with this simple short declaration `s := []int{}`. So when I need to add the value, I just need to append it: `s = append(s, value)`. Thank you for the answer btw, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AlifRamdani a slice is still allocating memory for an array with an initial set length and `append` allocates more space if you exceed the initial array's capacity. If you know more or less how many items the array is going to contain, you might have better performance if you set the initial capacity (allocating new memory is relatively expensive).

Answer (score 22):

In my opinion, this results from confusion over the usage of the `new` and `make` functions. This is a known issue/feature in the Go language, as evidenced by several discussions about `new` vs `make` at [golang-nuts](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts).

The difference between `new` and `make` may become clearer by letting Go print out the type of the value created by `new` and `make`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%T  %v\n", new([10]int), new([10]int))
    fmt.Printf("%T  %v\n", make([]int, 10), make([]int, 10))
}
```

The output:

```
*[10]int  &[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[]int  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

As can be seen from the type, to access an array element of `new([10]int)` we would first need to dereference the pointer.

Both `new` and `make` require a Go type as their 1st argument. However, the expression `[elems]int` is *not* a Go type (unless `elems` is a Go constant, which isn't the case here).

For further reference, see http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Allocation and http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#The_zero_value.

To get a better understanding of whether the result of `new` is usable, it may be helpful to lookup whether `len` and `cap` work with zero (nil) values: http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Length_and_capacity

Answer (score 4):

See The Go Programming Language Specification

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants

It says:"The length is part of the array's type; it must evaluate to a non- negative **constant** representable by a value of type int. "

Constants by no means vary.